# Populating a Listview with ORMLite and return the ID

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, ormlite

i'm trying to create a listview with the data from one table. I want to get the list with the field "name" of the table but when selected i want it to return the field "ID".

```
mapDao = new MapDao(connSource, Map.class);

List<Map> maps;
maps = mapDao.queryForAll();
ListView mapList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mapList);

//??????//
setContentView(mapList);
```

How do i insert the "name"s in the list and then get the ID?

(Sorry for my English...)

**Edit:**

Hmm, from what I found, I have to use an Adapter... a ArrayAdapater? a CursorAdapter? I don't know.  I don't think I can use a "List" on the Adapters?